# Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I am following a tutorial on how to set up a basic mvc in Nodejs using the hapi server and a few other packages.

**Tutorial**: https://www.sitepoint.com/node-js-mvc-application/

**Git for my project**: https://github.com/christoph88/node-js-mvc-tut/

I have an error when I try to launch the server:

```
~/Projects/node-js-mvc-tut$ node server.js 
/home/christoph/Projects/node-js-mvc-tut/server.js:33
Models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/christoph/Projects/node-js-mvc-tut/server.js:33:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Model is defined within the requirements. I do not understand why sync is undefined. Sequelise is required within the lib/index.js file.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Hoek = require('hoek');
const Path = require('path');
const Settings = require('./settings');
const Routes = require('./lib/routes');
const Models = require('./lib/models/');

const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ port: Settings.port });

server.register([
    require('vision'),
    require('inert')
], (err) => {
  Hoek.assert(!err, err);

  server.views({
    engines: { pug: require('pug') },
    path: Path.join(__dirname, 'lib/views'),
    compileOptions: {
      pretty: false
    },
    isCached: Settings.env === 'production'
  });

  // Add routes
  server.route(Routes);
});

Models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  server.start((err) => {
    Hoek.assert(!err, err);
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
  });
});
```

Can somebody help me with this? Would be great to get this running so I can try to adapt it to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working by moving my index.js file to the models folder.

This file has the necessairy scripts that dispatches sequelise in the model thus fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have exported the db in index.js

```
module.exports = db
```

and declared a db variable at the beginning of the file

```
var db = {}
```