# async/await with klaw module

Tags: node.js, async-await, node-modules

when server Node.js starts I catch error

> (node:2320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'sync' of undefined

in app.js

```
const specs = require('./swagger')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const config = require('../config/config')
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(specs.default))

require('./passport')
require('./routes')(app)

async function fn () {
    const { sequelize } = await require('./models')
    await sequelize.sync({ force: false })
        .then(() => {
            app.listen(config.development.port)
            console.log(`Server started on port ${config.development.port}`)
        })
}

// call fn
fn().then(module.exports = app)
```

file where I have properties for sequelize in folder './models'

```
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.development.database,
    config.development.username,
    config.development.password,
    {
        dialect: config.development.dialect,
        host: config.development.host
    }
)

const klaw = require('klaw')
const through2 = require('through2')

const excludeDirFilter = through2.obj(function (item, enc, next) {
    if (!item.stats.isDirectory()) this.push(item)
    next()
})

async function fn () {
    await klaw(__dirname)
        .pipe(excludeDirFilter)
        .on('data', item => {
            if (path.basename(item.path) !== 'index.js') {
                const model = sequelize.import(item.path)
                db[model.name] = model
            }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log(1)
        })

    await Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
        if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
            db[modelName].associate(db)
            console.log(2)
        }
    })

    db.sequelize = sequelize
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize
}

// call fn
fn().then(module.exports = db)
```

The story began with the fact that I need to get a list of all the files in the folder and subfolders of models, for this I used npm -i klaw. But then as I understand recursive search execution time began to take more time and so I tried to use async/await. Which led to the current error. The theme for me is new and difficult to understand. Thank you in advance

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410460/cannot-read-property-sync-of-undefined

Comment: no it's not the same situation

`fs
 .readdirSync(__dirname)
 .filter((file) =>
  file !== 'index.js'
 )
 .forEach((file) => {
  const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
  db[model.name] = model
 })`

if i use this code instead klaw module everything works fine, but I need searching all models in subfolders. 

May be i should another function? Not klaw for searching models in subfolders?

May be sequelize does not support model creation from subfolders?

Comment: See this too. https://github.com/jprichardson/node-klaw